# get user information by account name or e-mail for users that are not in the site's user list using javascript in 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, web-services, user

I have either a user's e-mail address or account name. I need to get their other information like name, department and title.

Everything I have read online only works if the user in question is in the site's user list and that only gets populated, from my understanding, in one of three ways:

1. user is given access to the site
2. user tries to access the site
3. user's name is selected in a people picker field and the form is saved

I thought I read somewhere that I could use one service to get account name from e-mail and then another server that would get user information from account name but I cannot find it now.

Ideally I'd like something that allows bulk operations. Meaning I have a bulk of account names or a bulk of e-mail addresses (the two will never be mixed).

I'm trying to do this in SharePoint 2010 using JavaScript. I am familiar with web-services (like list.asmx) or CSOM but am open to learning a new way if what I want to do is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the `GetUserProfileByName` of `UserProfileService.asmx` to get information for users even if they are not in the site collection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981482(v=office.12).aspx